# How to create a title with a border ribbon behind it using pseudo elements?

Tags: html, css

I'm learning CSS (having a lot of fun with it!) and was wondering if anyone had an alternative solution for this.

I want to have a dynamic title for a site that has a ribbon behind it. So no matter the length of the title text, the ribbon behind it will "resize". My solution is to have a background container for the text that overlays on top of the ribbon. As the text container resizes, it will look like the ribbon behind it grows/shrinks because of the white background.

[Below is the code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOYQzV) of my solution for a dynamic title with ribbon behind it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="body">
  <div class="title_rule_wrap">
    <div class="title_rule">
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.title_rule_wrap {
  text-align: center;
  width: 600px;
  height: 0;
  margin: 30px 0 20px;
  border-bottom: 7px solid green;
}

.title_rule {
  background-color: #fff;
  top: -2.2em;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.body {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Would my solution above be possible using only a single h1 tag and psuedo elements? [Here is what I have so far](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNKRQe) for an alternative solution.

Thanks in advance for your help. Cheers.

Comment: why is the code in your pen different than the code you posted? here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/tp1vztfm/)

Comment: The first link is for the posted code. The second link at the bottom is my attempt at an alternative solution that I need help with.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin:0 0 0 0;
  padding:0;
}
h1:before {
  content: "";
  position:relative;
  top:-3px;
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid green;
}
h1:after {
  content: "";
  position:relative;
  top:5px;
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

This puts a green border before and after the `h1`, and it resizes based on the browser width and height as its position is set as relative.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't really think this is a good solution (I think what you already have may be better - the widths for the `:before` and `:after` is the tricky part), this is the only way I could achieve what you are asking.

The good side is it is responsive!

```
h1 {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
h1:after, h1:before {
  content: "";
  background:green;
  width:33%;
  height:6px;
  margin:0 10px;
}
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPMqGd)

Here is another variation using `display:inline-block;` instead of `flex`

```
h1 {
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
}
h1:after, h1:before {
  content: "";
  background:green;
  width:33%;
  height:6px;
  margin:0 10px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```